# Skipping options from parameters.yml in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I created application with Symfony2 and set parameters:

```
parameters:
    database_driver:   pdo_mysql
    database_host:     127.0.0.1
    database_port:     ~
    database_name:     database_example_name
    database_user:     example_username
    database_password: ****
```

And when application tries to connect to database and get error that it can't connect to db because. I don't use a password what it is wrong because I have it in parameters.yml.

This is the error:

```
SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'example_username'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I checked in cache file, which is generated based on parameters.yml and I can see that it set password to `NULL`:

appDevDebugProjectContainer.php

```
(...)
return $this->services['doctrine.dbal.default_connection'] = $this->get('doctrine.dbal.connection_factory')->createConnection(array('host' => 'localhost', 'port' => NULL, 'user' => 'root', 'password' => NULL, 'driver' => 'pdo_mysql', 'driverOptions' => array()), $b, $c, array());
(...)
```

I tried of course to clear cache but it didn't help.

What could it be?

I don't know if it related but before installing Sonata (Admin, FOS, User) there was no problem.

Comment: Then why are there **** ? I get that you want to cover the original, but simply don't put there any value.

Comment: Do check the `config.yml` in order to make sure that `Doctrine` is using `%database_password%` parameter for connection.

Comment: I checked - `config.yml` uses %database_password%...

Comment: Are you maybe overruling the %database_password% in another file? A development version or instance version of the parameters perhaps?

Comment: It's dumb but you should test the same username and password by using phpmyadmin (or  mysql via console) to test if you can log in database. Also are you sure of your mysql server & port ? If you have special chars in your password, I advice you to add "" or '' to avoid YAML problem

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an OS which has SELinux, do the following settings

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db=1
```

Answer (score 0):

As Sybio commented I would first check if the logins works in phpmyadmin or via SSH.

This works fine for me on localhost

```
database_driver: pdo_mysql
database_host: 127.0.0.1
database_port: null
database_name: database_name
database_user: username
database_password: password
```

So if the logins works your problem probably doesn't come from the parameters.yml, we need to see your config.yml (at least doctrine, fos & sonata configs) that's the next likely suspect.